# Sending a webhook via google tag manager

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm using google tag manager in my website, I would like to send a http request to a 3rd party service incase someone visits a specific page.

the trigger is setup well, what i'm trying to figure is if the url for post is for example:

"https://hook.eu1.make.com/g88t9og168tfh4uejyh55j5hbao7nutw" how do I wrap it in custom code so it will fire everytime the page is loaded? any javascript examples ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible. Add a custom html tag in Tag Manager which fires on the pages you want.
Add and change this code into the html tag:

```
<script>
  var headers = new Headers();
  headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
  var body = {
    "yourdata": yourdata,
    "user_agent": navigator.userAgent,
    "url": window.location.origin + window.location.pathname
  };
  var options = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: headers,
    mode: "cors",
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
  };

fetch("https://hook.eu1.make.com/YOUR_WEBHOOK", options);

</script>
```

Comment: Would it be possible to fetch the dataLayer that triggered this event here? Imagine the trigger is "On custom event" and the page is firing `scroll` event with some parameters like the depth of the scroll. Could we get it here?